# How do I disable automatic updates on OpenSUSE 12.2

Tags: linux, opensuse, update

For reasons unknown, OpenSUSE seems to have half a dozen different places that mention auto-update. Is there a way I can definitely, permanently, irreversibly *disable* auto-update so that new software will never, ever, under any circumstances, be installed? Ideally I want to prevent the OS from even connecting to the Internet to see *if* any updates are available.

I've unchecked half a dozen things, but I'm still getting alerts telling me updates are available. *I do now want updates!* I can't believe this is so hard to turn off...

In case it makes any difference, OpenSUSE 12.2 with a GNOME desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full details of how the system works can be found on the [OpenSUSE wiki page for Zypper](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Zypper_usage_11.3). Zypper is the bases for all of the auto-update functions in OpenSUSE.

Probably the best way to stop any update, ever, is to remove all of the software repositories from Zypper.

To get a list of them, run:

```
zypper lr
```

Which will give you a list of every source of annoying updates.

```
#  | Alias                          | Name                         | Enabled | Refresh
---+--------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+--------
 1 | Mozilla-12.2                   | Mozilla Updates              | Yes     | No
```

You can then use this information with the `zypper rr` command, or RemoveRepo

```
zypper rr 1
zypper rr Mozilla-12.2
zypper rr "Mozilla Updates"
```

Remove them all, and you'll never have a package auto-update again.

If you actually do want to update once in a while, but want to control it, you can instead *disable* all of your repos until you want to enable them for update.

```
zypper mr -d Mozilla-12.2    # disables the Mozilla repo
zypper mr -e Mozilla-12.2    # enables the Mozilla repo
zypper mr -a -d              # disable all repos
zypper mr -a -e              # enable all repos
```

While I'm on the topic, you can get a list of updates through the `zypper lu` command, and can select individual updates through `zypper install [packagename]`.